# Fazer Scrollbar de DIV seguir elemento li da lista

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, gostaria de saber como eu posso fazer com que o código que eu tenho (abaixo) faça com que toda vez que o botão "*próximo*" ou "*anterior*" forem clicados, sigam o elemento  *li* com a classe "*music-playing*"?

Código: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vnprg

Quero fazer com que a barra de rolagem deixe em foco o elemento LI com a classe.
Fique seguindo o elemento toda vez que a classe for trocada.
Dá forma atual, a rolagem está dessincronizada, indo para cima e para baixo.

Comment: Não entendi bem o que você quer. Visualizei aqui e pareceu funcionar direito.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo: Ele não está seguindo corretamente a li com a classe que adicionei.

Se você seguir somente para frente ou somente para trás, verá que ele perde o foco do li com a classe.

Comment: @gumaro Pelo que entendi seu problema é com a rolagem que aparentemente fica zoada. É isso mesmo?

Comment: @EdgarMunizBerlinck exato!

Comment: Sugiro que você atualize sua pergunta para descrever melhor os pontos em que o pessoal ficou em dúvida... Eu próprio, depois de ler tudo, ainda não entendi qual é o efeito que você quer.

Comment: @RuiPimentel está mais compreensível agora?

Comment: Está mais compreensível :) porém, ainda tem uma coisa que não entendo. Tentei rodar o CodePen que você mandou no Chrome (sistema Ubuntu) e nada aconteceu; na realidade, meu console acusa erro fatal já no carregamento.

Comment: @RuiPimentel atualizei o CodePen, tente agora!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa neste caso de subtrair a posição do `#playlist` usando `scrollTop: $(proximo).offset().top - $('#playlist').offset().top`.

Deixo também uma sugestão para comprimir o código:

```
$("#playlist-content input[type=button]").click(function(){  
  var playing = $('#playlist li.music-playing');
  $('#playlist li').removeClass('music-playing');
  var proximo = this.id == 'next' ? playing.next() : playing.prev();
  if (!proximo.length) proximo = playing;
                proximo.addClass('music-playing');  
  $('#music').animate({
    scrollTop: $(proximo).offset().top - $('#playlist').offset().top
 }, 500);

});
```

#### http://codepen.io/sergiocrisostomo/pen/yFleu

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda :p